# CPU optimized compiled debian packages

Tags: debian, gentoo, packaging, optimization

I really don't know how the Debian maintainers check for all the bugs in every release of Debian, but isn't it the case that if all codes for every package have been patched up and tested for all CPU architectures listed, then releasing them with CPU optimization would be easy?? I mean, for CPU optimization, isn't it all up to the compiler and there's no chance of bugs suddenly appearing?

Alright, I'm NOT YET looking for a Gentoo Linux derived system where I can compile every software with all the CPU optimization that's available to my hardware. Maybe there's a Debian-like repository out there that has the most common optimizations like SSE and those other extensions. Is there? I don't really mind aggressively compiled binaries that in total are no better than the standard Debian packages.

If not, as stated above, then I will be looking for a Portage-like (from Gentoo Linux) system that runs on Debian that will let me automate all the compilation and .deb-wrapping of all "Source Packages" from the Debian repositories. Are there any of that?

Comment: Are you saying you want to rebuild all the packages in a Debian repository with different compilation flags of your choosing? That would be a monumental endeavour, but is certainly possible, I think. https://wiki.debian.org/DebianBootstrap#Specifying_profiles.2Fstages is somewhat relevant.

Comment: The first flaw in your assumptions is that optimizations never introduce new bugs. The second flaw in your assumptions is that compiling with all possible iterations of optimizations *is even remotely worth the hassle*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build specific packages according to your own liking, you could use the [Gentoo prefix project](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Prefix). It allows you to compile and  install packages to a specific directory, as a regular user. This way you can enjoy the flexibility and repositories of Gentoo, without breaking or changing your system.

Answer (score -1):

You could switch to Gentoo and use the bindist use flag globally. This will download binary files when available to avoid compiling everything. Then you could remove the flag for individual packages that you would like optimized.

Comment: The `bindist` useflag enables or disables features that impact redistributability. It disables the official Firefox branding, for example.